# BigQuery: Checking the content of an array with using UNNEST

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, unnest

I've been trying for the past hours to look for a way to check in BigQuery if an array contains a certain value without using UNNEST. The reason why I don't want to use UNNEST is that I don't want an UNNEST result, I just want to check if the value is in it or not (and then do a condition CASE WHEN on it).

I've tried different ways like value = ANY(array), CONTAINS, CONTAINS_ARRAY but none of them work on BigQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide your table schema?

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for you not to use ***UNNEST*** is the unnested result, I would not leave this option behind. Although, I would suggest you to use UNNEST and do not select the unnested columns. Thus, maintaining your nested result and you will be able to use these temporary new columns to verify your conditions within your ***CASE WHEN*** statements.

I have used a [public dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=firebase-public-project&d=analytics_153293282&t=events_20181003&page=table) in BigQuery to exemplify this algorithm for you.The syntax is:

```
WITH
  temporary_table AS(
  SELECT
    *,
    param
  FROM
    `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003`,
    UNNEST(event_params) AS param )
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN (param.key IN ('value', 'board')) THEN TRUE
END
  AS check
FROM
  temporary_table
LIMIT
  100;
```

Notice that the *unnested columns* from ***event_param*** are not displayed in the final result. Also, the column ***check*** was created and used as a Boolean which could be omitted and could also be used as flag to make the desired modification to your desired columns.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it but it seems like it doesn't work, I'm still working to find a solution

Comment: @Rob, could you please inform if you got any errors? Or what exactly you are expecting from the results?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I found a way around, instead of trying to find a solution without unnesting, I unnested and filtered. It helped me to get the results I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [1,2,3] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [4,5]
)
SELECT id, arr,
  CASE 1 IN UNNEST(arr) 
    WHEN TRUE THEN 'valie is in array'
    ELSE 'valie is not in array'
  END conclusion
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

[image]

As you can see, result is not unnested!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your solution but it doesn't look like it gives the solution I'm looking for, I will update if I can find the solution

Comment: can you be more specific please?! explain what is not as expected and ideally what exactly you are expecting

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I found a way around, instead of trying to find a solution without unnesting, I unnested and filtered. It helped me to get the results I wanted. Thanks!